# How can I click on a button on the same element with a specific name?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, antd

This is ant-react project.
html:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="head">
                 <span>name 1</span>   
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div>
                    <button>done</button>
                </div> 
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="head">
                 <span>name 2</span>   
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div>
                    <button>done</button>
                </div> 
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
cy.get(`div:contains('name1')`)
  .should('be.visible')
  .invoke('show') 
  .should('be.visible') 
  .find('button:contains("Done")').eq(0).click({ multiple: true })
```

There are a lot of item elements. I need to click on the 'Done' button of the element with name "name 1".
But every time i get error:

```
Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.
```

...

Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.

How can I do it?

Comment: In react you should use JSX and inside of that you can define `onClick` attribute to call a function.. Your code is not react code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. The first parent will go to `<div class="head">` and the next parent will move to `div` just above. Now using within we will make sure that the **Done** button is clicked for `name 1`.

```js
cy.contains('span', 'name1')
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.contains('button', 'done').click()
  })
```